SQL Server jobs running at same time... trying to to check to see if one is running
I am trying to check to see if competing SQL Jobs are running since they share the same table. We want to ensure that one does not block the other by locking the table.
The problem is we have a job that runs every 15secs and we check to see if a job is already running first. But no matter what (meaning if there is not a job running) it will not run. However if I take the EXACT same query and manually run it in SSIS, it runs perfectly.
Here is the query:
declare @return_value int,
    @messagesUpdated int,
    @dlrsDeleted int
    
if not exists ( 
    select 1
    from msdb.dbo.sysjobs_view job 
    inner join msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity activity on job.job_id = activity.job_id
    where 
        activity.run_Requested_date is not null 
    and activity.stop_execution_date is null 
    )
    
begin
exec @return_value = [dbo].[updateDeliveryReceipts]
    @messagesUpdated = @messagesUpdated OUTPUT,
    @dlrsDeleted = @dlrsDeleted OUTPUT
end
select  @messagesUpdated as N'@messagesUpdated',
    @dlrsDeleted as N'@dlrsDeleted'

select  'Return Value' = @return_value

But if I take this check to see if a Job is currently running.... it runs just fine.
if not exists (  
    select 1
    from msdb.dbo.sysjobs_view job 
    inner join msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity activity on job.job_id = activity.job_id
    where 
        activity.run_Requested_date is not null 
    and activity.stop_execution_date is null 
)

I know this is probably a simple fix... but for the life of me cannot figure it out.
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks

SQL Server 2017 Standard running on Windows Server


Please clarify exactly what you mean by "job" here. Your post doesn't mention SQL Server Agent at all.

You do realise that SQL tables are designed to be accessed by multiple processes at the same time, yes maybe one process might have to wait a moment for the other if they are both accessing similar records... but serialising access it an anti-pattern.

If you execute this code in a SQL Agent job then isn't there going to be a SQL Agent job running? (i.e.: itself.)

Also why not just let it block waiting for the other process to finish?

Here is something we use. If you want Job B to check if Job A is still running, and wait until Job A finishes, then put this script as the first Step in Job B. Change @JobName to the name of the Job you want to wait for.
DECLARE @JobName SYSNAME;
SET @JobName = 'Job A';

WHILE 1 = 1
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity ja 
            LEFT JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory jh ON ja.job_history_id = jh.instance_id
            JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs j ON ja.job_id = j.job_id
            JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps js ON ja.job_id = js.job_id
                AND ISNULL(ja.last_executed_step_id, 0) + 1 = js.step_id
        WHERE
            ja.session_id = (
                SELECT TOP 1 session_id FROM msdb.dbo.syssessions ORDER BY agent_start_date DESC
            )
            AND start_execution_date IS NOT NULL
            AND stop_execution_date IS NULL
            AND j.name = @JobName
        )
        BEGIN
            PRINT @JobName + ' is currently running. Waiting 15 minutes to check again.';
            WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:15'
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            PRINT @JobName + ' is not running. We are good to go!'
            BREAK;
        END
END

DISCLAIMER: I didn't write this. Someone else at my job did. I do not really know the full implications of having a loop constantly running in a Job Step, but can only say nothing noticeable has ever happned on our server.
